# preventing double-connection over wlan0 and usb 0 in network-manager-gnome

Tags: debian, networkmanager

I have a TP-Link umts router. The most time I am connect over wlan to it.

Some times the Router have no Power of course so I connect him over an usb cable to my Notebook. Network-Manager-gnome connect him again as an ether-connection but do not close the wlan connection. I mußt do this manually. How can I tell Network-manager if Network interface USB 0 is available connect but close my wlan-connection too. Can I do this over a skript under `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` ? And how?  Or something wrong in my configuration.

```
LANG=C cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Digiworld 
[connection]
id=Digiworld
uuid=cf380e60-ae56-405e-ba6c-82913b308d14
type=wifi
timestamp=1479637021

[wifi]
ssid=Digiworld
mode=infrastructure
mac-address=20:7C:8F:01:A1:61
security=802-11-wireless-security

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk-flags=1

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
method=ignore
ip6-privacy=0
```

And conf from ether-connection

```
LANG=C cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Kabelgebundene\ Verbindung\ 2 
[ethernet]
duplex=full
mac-address=92:3D:73:D7:5A:62

[connection]
id=Kabelgebundene Verbindung 2
uuid=a8358ccf-6fdb-43ec-bad8-4c406a2d0307
type=ethernet
timestamp=1487757956

[ipv6]
method=auto
ip6-privacy=0

[ipv4]
method=auto
```

Comment: I solved it for me with an udev rule and a systemd unit. thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks bengal for the hint. But in my case I has to adapt it, because I have an ethernetcard to. And if I plug off the the router it removes completly in nmcli, the devicenode is not static, maybe the Umts-router switched in modem-modus. This seemd to work for me (german)

```
#!/bin/bash
                 enable_disable_wifi ()
       {
            result=$(nmcli device | grep "usb0")
            if [ -n "$result" ]; then
                 nmcli radio wifi off
            else
                 nmcli radio wifi on
            fi
       }

       if [ "$2" != "usb0" ]; then
            enable_disable_wifi
       fi

       if [ "$2" = "usb0" ]; then
       enable_disable_wifi
       fi
```

Probably dowdy. And no suffix sh to the skript. that do not work

Answer (score 0):

The `nmcli-examples` man page has an example of NetworkManager dispatcher script to disable Wi-Fi when an Ethernet connection is activated and turn Wi-Fi on again when Ethernet is disconnected:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LC_ALL=C

enable_disable_wifi ()
{
    result=$(nmcli dev | grep "ethernet" | grep -w "connected")
    if [ -n "$result" ]; then
        nmcli radio wifi off
    else
        nmcli radio wifi on
    fi
}

if [ "$2" = "up" ]; then
    enable_disable_wifi
fi

if [ "$2" = "down" ]; then
    enable_disable_wifi
fi
```

From the man page:

> Name this script e.g. 70-wifi-wired-exclusive.sh and put it into
>   /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/ directory. See NetworkManager(8)
>   manual page for more information about NetworkManager dispatcher
>   scripts.